# Operator overloading problems C++

Tags: c++

I have a Polynomial class and I have overloaded the +,-, and * operators, as well as the << operator.
It all seems to work fine until I try to output an expression such as poly1+poly2 rather than just a single Polynomial object.

Here is my addition operator code:

```
Polynomial operator+ (const Polynomial& poly1, const Polynomial& poly2){
    vector<int> final_coeffs;

    if (poly1.Degree()>poly2.Degree())
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=poly2.Degree(); i++)
            final_coeffs.push_back(poly2.Coefficient(i) + poly1.Coefficient(i));
        for (int i=poly2.Degree()+1; i<=poly1.Degree(); i++)
            final_coeffs.push_back(poly1.Coefficient(i));
    }

    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=poly1.Degree(); i++)
            final_coeffs.push_back(poly1.Coefficient(i) + poly2.Coefficient(i));
        for (int i=poly1.Degree()+1; i<=poly2.Degree(); i++)
            final_coeffs.push_back(poly2.Coefficient(i));
    }

    return Polynomial(final_coeffs);
}
```

And here is my << operator code (I already have a correctly working print member function):

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Polynomial& poly){
    poly.print();
    return out;
}
```

The problem arises when I try to do this in main:

```
cout << poly1+poly2;
```

But works fine if I just do:

```
cout << poly1;
```

The error message says: *Invalid operands to binary expression ('ofstream' (aka 'basic_ofstream') and ('Polynomial')*

And for the specific function it should be using: *Candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 2nd argument*

Thank you!

Comment: `operator+` should be implemented in terms of `operator+=`.

Comment: Well, the error message is correct -- make the second param of operator<< const.

Comment: Your `operator<<` ignores its `ostream` argument and just outputs to whatever stream `print()` uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Polynomial const& poly) {
```

This is because a temporary object cannot be bound to a non-const reference.

Note that this means you also must make  the `Polynomial::print()` function be `const`.